# Ant buildfile does not contain a javac task

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have build.xml file and I want to create Java project from Existing Ant Buildfile. But I have an error: **Specified buildfile does not contain a javac task**
My file has simple structure:

```
<project>
     <target ...>
     </target>
     ...
</project>
```

Comment: And does it have a javac task? What do you expect eclipse to do if your build file doesn't consist in compiling Java source code?

Comment: You can specify macros that build all the projects, similar to a parent/module setup with Maven.  I am having the same problem; I can build the project from the command line but cannot import into Eclipse.

Answer (score 10):

Provide javac to your build.xml as below:

```
<javac srcdir="src" destdir="bin" />
```

Comment: Even though I only include other build.xml files in my top level build.xml, I provided just some javac task with srcdir pointing to the top level directory to make Eclipse happy ;). Now I can see all sources and all underlying build.xml files, I can import them to Ant View and execute their targets.

Answer (score 3):

As Puneet Pandey pointed out, this error occurs when your `build.xml` file is lacking a `<javac>` XML element.

The `<javac>` XML element in the `build.xml` file (referred to as [javac task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html)) tells the compiler or IDE (Eclipse in this case) where the source Java files are for compiling. Once you know that it should be quite clear why Eclipse can't import your `build.xml` without a `<javac>` XML element.

In case you are not sure where to stick the `<javac>` tag I'll add a slightly fuller example. You will need to navigate to your `build.xml` and edit it so that it contains the `<javac>` line in the appropriate section **inside** the `<project>` tag.

```
<project ...>
  <javac srcdir="src" destdir="bin" />
  <target ...>
  </target>
  ...
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this,

```
    <target name="compile">
  <javac destdir="build/classes" srcdir="src" includeantruntime="false">
    <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
  </javac>
  </target>

    <target name="war" depends="compile">   
  <war destfile="build/${name}.war" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">
   <fileset dir="WebContent" casesensitive="no">
   </fileset>
   <lib dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib"/>
   <classes dir="build/classes">
   </classes>   
  </war>
</target>
```